# SQL join master details table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two tables in SQL server:

**Product:**

```
SELECT Id, Name From Product

x------x--------------------x
| Id   |        Name        |
x------x--------------------x
|  1   |          A         |
|  2   |          B         |
|  3   |          C         |
x------x--------------------x
```

**Order:**

```
SELECT Id, Order_Date, QTY From Order

x------x--------------------x-------x
|  Id  |   Order_Date       |   QTY |
x------x--------------------x-------x
|  1   |   2014-01-13       |   10  |
|  1   |   2014-01-11       |   15  |
|  1   |   2014-01-12       |   20  |
|  2   |   2014-01-06       |   30  |
|  2   |   2014-01-08       |   40  |
x------x--------------------x-------x
```

I would like to get a table which contains list of all products and if there is any order placed  for the product.

**Example:**

```
x------x--------------------x
| Id   |        Has_Order   |
x------x--------------------x
|  1   |          1         |
|  2   |          1         |
|  3   |          0         |
x------x--------------------x
```

I tried left outer join but it includes all the rows from Order table. What is the most efficient way to write this SQL query?

Comment: do a distinct after the left join

Comment: thanks dmg, I think it will require a group by too to check if there is any row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists` in a subquery:

```
select p.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from orders o where o.id = p.id)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as order_exists_flag
from products p;
```

For performance, you want an index on `orders(id)`.  I would expect this to be the fastest approach.

Comment: these types of queries are very inefficient. One subquery might be executed per tuple in the main relation.

Comment: I also think this is the fastest approach.

Comment: @dmg . . . (1) You should try it.  (2) All rows in the `products` table are being returned anyway, so work has to be done for every row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The query works, no question about it. For a small table, it does not matter. For a larger one, a join is more efficient.

Comment: @dmg . . . I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option to consider

```
Select ID 
      ,Has_Order = max(Flg)
 From  (
        Select ID,Flg = 0 From [Product]
        Union All
        Select Distinct ID,Flg = 1 From [Order]
       ) src
 Group By ID
```

Comment: . . I would be quite surprised if this had decent performance.  `select distinct` on all orders is going to be quite expensive.  Even if an index can be used for that, then the outer aggregation cannot use an index.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You may be a little surprised.  Comparing the two approaches the batch is 49% / 51%  ... or 294ms vs 271ms  you clearly win, but it was not apples and oranges.  My "orders" table (closest fit) is 1.7MM rows and is indexed on "ID".

Comment: . . That is quite interesting.  I think aggregation on small tables is so fast that it messes up my intuition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Full Disclosure.  If I put a filter on "products"  the batch changes to 81% / 19%   258ms vs 169ms  a more pronounced victory for your approach.